# UDP to serial emulator

Tags: serial-port, udp, emulation, virtual

does anyone know a software based solution to emulate a virtual COM interface with UDP as an input? I want to send sensor data from an Arduino via Ethernet. The existing software for the sensor is using a serial interface. Therefore I need a method to emulate a COM port.

Comment: Emulating a serial port with a network driver is very common.  Lots of device manufacturers upgraded their device interface from 1980s hardware and left the programmatic interface the same by emulating a serial port.  But nobody ever picks UDP, always TCP.  UDP just doesn't make any sense, too lossy.  Use google to find products, start with "tcp serial port emulator".

Answer (score 0):

COM Port Data Emulator is a tool for emulating a com port or an Ethernet device, that generates a serial stream of data. The program can create a data flow, wrap it to data packets (RS232, TCP/IP or UDP) and send to a port.